# Japanese cotton cheesecake deflating

Tags: cheesecake

I have used a lot of recipes for Japanese cotton cheesecake, but none of them have worked well for me. I am currently using the following recipe and method:

- 60 gr of full milk
- 140 gr of cream cheese
- 40 gr butter
- 50 gr plain flour
- 15 gr cornstarch
- 5 eggs
- 100 gr fine sugar

Method: mix milk and cheese and add flour + cornstarch, then mix in the yolks. Make meringue and fold in.

Bake at 180C for 15 min, then lower the temperature to 160C and bake for 50 min.

Turn off the oven and leave the cake in the oven for 1 hour.

My problem: the cake is rising well during baking but then it deflates when it cools in the oven. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, i have seen this answer before and i have tried also the mentioned method (baking at 180C first 15 min and then at 160C ) but it did not work for me either. Are there any egg whites stabilization tricks to avoid deflating

Comment: If you don't include what you've already researched or already tried in your question, then people are going to waste time & effort coming up with duplicate suggestions. Please dit your question to include all salient detail.